# Creating a simple array from a node list not working as an IIFE

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array on the fly using a variable declaration and an IIFE, although it seems to not be adding each item to the array. Take this html for example:

```
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
<div>test</div>
```

And this javascript:

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

const divsTwo = [...divs]; // not IE compatible

const divsThree = (function() {
    let arr = [];

    for (let item of divs) {
        arr.push[item];
    }

    return arr;
})();

// logging
console.log(divs); // correctly logs node list
console.log(divsTwo); // correctly logs array (right?)
console.log(divsThree); //* logs an empty (incorrect) array
```

I essentially want to just replicate `divsTwo` (via `divsThree`) so that it's IE compatible. Can someone point out why the third variable isn't the same as the second? Thanks for any help here

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/JjdrZyP

Comment: `arr.push()`, not `arr.push[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment shows you are using `Array.prototype.push` incorrectly. Still there's a better way.

Use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to turn any iterable into an array -

```
const divs =
  document.querySelectorAll('div')

const myArr =
  Array.from(divs)

console.log(myArr)
// [div, div, div, ..., div]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers it looks like you just have a typo and are trying to call `arr.push[]` instead of `arr.push()` (note the use of parens instead of brackets).

However, as far as IE goes, the standard way to make the list of DOM nodes an array is as follows:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

var divsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(divs);
```

Note that I'm using `var` as `const` isn't IE compatible either.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in your for loop i think. Try

```js
 for (let item in divs) {
        arr.push[item];
    }
```